# CFileDialog with checkbox in mfc vc++

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

We want to create a custom CFileDialog with a Custom checkbox.
I could get the CheckBox in the UI but no sure how to get the checkbox checked state in return.

```
CSpecialFileDialog: CFileDialog{
 //constructor
}
//From Mainframe i am calling this dialog.
CSpecialDialog(TRUE);
```

which opens the filedialog with checkbox but i am not able to get the checkbox checked state.

Comment: Show how you are adding the check box. Are you using the modern UI for Vista and above (recommended), or is this XP compatible? `AddCheckButton` and `GetCheckButtonState` will do it for modern UI.

Comment: I created a dialog with the checkbox only and made this dialog style as "Child". Also, i am not using AddCheckButton and GetCheckButtonState. I am a beginner to mfc vc++ project. There may be a possibility that the approach i used is in correct. If any you knows the best approach or have a sample for it. please do post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Vista, and newer Windows versions, use new APIs which can be accessed in Visual Studio 2008 and newer. You can enable "Visual Styles" (the last parameter in `CFileDialog` is set to `TRUE`)

Then add checkbox and other controls as follows:

```
CFileDialog dlg(TRUE, 0, 0, 0,
    L"All Files|*.*|" , this, 0, TRUE);

const int check_id = 101;
dlg.AddCheckButton(check_id, L"checkbox name", TRUE);

if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
{
    BOOL check;
    dlg.GetCheckButtonState(check_id, check);
    TRACE(L"reading the value for check_id %d\n", check);
}
```